# Create a flow with IntegrationFlow that's close after certain time if no messages are sends

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm building a system that's create flows dynamically, but sometimes messages stop being received. So i wanna make a logic that stop the flow to receive messages or, if it is possible, destroy the flow after some time.

```
IntegrationFlows
.from(unicastReceivingChannelAdapter)
.<byte[], String>transform(String::new)
.handle(e -> processMessage((String)e.getPayload()))
 .get();
```

This is my flow until now. I register the flow using IntegrationFlowContext.register like below:

```
flowContext.registration(integrationFlow).register()
```

And add in a ArrayList, to use in other parts of the system

```
aircraft.getUdpFlows().add(flowContext.registration(integrationFlow).register())
```

It's possible to make something like that without using some thread to verify after some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible without some scheduled task to check the system state at some point. Even if such a feature (`IdleEvent` ?) would be implemented in the framework, it still would be based on the scheduler and some interval between active and non-active states.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help